# Could we define a function whose output is another function defined in the body in Python

Tags: python

Here is a part of my code:

```
def Myfunction(Stream):
    import MyLibA
    return Stream.Id(), MyLibA.City('America')

import MyLibB.action as action
result = action.mapStream(Myfunction)
```

We can see that there is no variable for function `Myfunction` and I am not allowed to change the definition of `action` (namely I cannot change the variables of function `Myfunction`).

Now I need to run a loop of list of cities (the variable `America` in function `Myfunction`):

```
cityList = ['China', 'America', 'Janpan']
```

Naively, I have to manually change the variable `America` in `Myfunction` and run it one by one.

How could I pass a variable to `Myfunction`?

Could we define a function whose return is another function. And the pausi-code of the idea something like (it's not a correct code, just what I want to implement):

```
cityList = ['China', 'America', 'Janpan']

def function(city):
    def Myfunction(Stream):
        import MyLibA
        return Stream.Id(), MyLibA.City(city)

    return Myfunction

for city in cityList:
    Myfunction = function(city)
    import MyLibB.action as action
    result = action.mapStream(Myfunction)
```

Comment: Why do you think that's not correct code?

Comment: @rdas purely followed by my mind, just a imaginary code of logic

Comment: Syntactically that's correct python. Haven't you tried it out yet?

Comment: ...........and?

Comment: @rdas i really works

Comment: Try with your actual code and see if that works or not.